# Responsive Game View - Game View Is Not Same At Different Screen Resolutions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, unity-ui

I need your information! I'm cloning the game called Toon Blast to improve myself. In the picture below, you can see 2 screenshots from the original game on the left, and 2 screenshots from my own version on the right. As you can notice, while the game board remains in the same form in the original game on the left, regardless of the screen, in my version on the right, I cannot get the game board I want other than the reference resolution.

Elements outside the game board use Canvas, but inside the game board I'm using a sprite renderer and I don't want to include the game board in the canvas. The location of the game board items in the hierarchy is shown in another picture.

I need your information on how to make the game board responsive.

[image]

I tried to make it using canvas but canvas is limiting me what i am trying to do. So each board item is a game object with sprite renderer component attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your tiles are not in unity canvas (and, actually, that's how it should be done), they are rendered with the camera. The camera will render all that is inside its frustum. So, in case of different aspect ratios, you need to update the camera's frustum size to be sure all your content is on the screen.

In [this section of Unity3d docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CameraTricks.html), you can find more info about camera frustum.